# How to get hover boxes to to be big enough to cover the nav items, and not to cover the whole section

Tags: css, flexbox, hover, nav

I am creating a navbar, and I want to make sure that the colored box when I hover on nav items are big enough to cover the words, but not so big they expand well below the items. This can be seen in the picture above.

I have set the height at 80px; is there any way I can keep the height of the nav at 80px, but still solve this issue?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH8Qt.png

Comment: Please provide relevant HTML and CSS. A screenshot is not enough for us to diagnose the problem...

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started.  Just needs styling.

```css
body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar {
      display: flex;
      background-color: #eee;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      height: 100px;
      color: black;
      border-top: 6px solid lightblue;
    }

    ul {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      list-style: none;
    }

    ul>li>a {
      padding: 3px 12px;
      color: black;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 0 24px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

    ul>li>a:hover {
      padding: 3px 12px;
      color: white;
      background: #ff6600;
      font-size: 16px;
      margin: 0 24px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;

    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
      ul>li>a {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0 6px;
      }
      
        ul>li>a:hover {
      
          font-size: 12px;
                  margin: 0 6px;

         

    }

    

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />

  <title>home</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href=""><strong>COLLECTIONS</strong></a></li>
      <li><a href="">ANIMATIONS</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ANIMATIONS</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ANIMATIONS</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ANIMATIONS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```